# JQuery draggable not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable

I have a quick snippet that allows me to insert a bookmark on a line and it also tells me at what percentage the bookmark is located from the right edge. I want to be able to drag these bookmarks while at the same time the text above the bookmark is changing to the appropriate percentage.

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bagofmilk/uKkRh/580).

But here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper'>
   <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  margin:40px 0px;
  border:1px solid white;
}

#container {
  background: green; 
  width: 500px; 
  height: 20px; 
  position: relative;
  margin-top:40px;
}
#wrapper img {
  position: absolute;   
}

span{font-size:62.5%;}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#container").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    var z = x - 5;       
    var txt = $('<span></span>');
    txt.css('top', '50px').css('left', z).css('position', 'absolute');
    txt.text( (Math.round((x.toFixed(0) / 5) * 1) / 1) + "%");
    txt.appendTo('#wrapper');

    var img = $('<img>');
    img.css('top', '65px').css('left', x).css('position', 'absolute').css('z-index', '999');
    img.attr('src', 'http://www.appmalt.info/htmlplay/img/arrowup.png');
    img.appendTo('#wrapper');

})

$('img').draggable();

});
```

I can't even drag the image and I don't know why. Can anyone explain?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bagofmilk/uKkRh/580) again.

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have called draggable on the img before adding it to the dom. Try below..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        var z = x - 5;       
        var txt = $('<span></span>');
        txt.css('top', '50px').css('left', z).css('position', 'absolute');
        txt.text( (Math.round((x.toFixed(0) / 5) * 1) / 1) + "%");
        txt.appendTo('#wrapper');

        var img = $('<img>');
        img.css('top', '65px').css('left', x).css('position', 'absolute').css('z-index', '999');
        img.attr('src', 'http://www.appmalt.info/htmlplay/img/arrowup.png');
        img.appendTo('#wrapper');
        $('img').draggable();
    })



});
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it! You will need to put in some code to make the label follow when dragged, but that's another question. ;)

Comment: You don't need to use `$('img').draggable()`, you can simply use `img.draggable();` as this is already a jQuery object.

Comment: Nice! When it will let me I'll award the answer. How do I make it so that it only drags in the "X" direction (horizontally)?

Answer (score 1):

`$('img').draggable();` only applies to currently existing images.

You need to manually call it again:

```
$('#container').click(function(e) {
  ...

  $(img).draggable();
});
```